# WSO2 DSS 3.5.1 Create a file based Scheduled task

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

Using WSO2 DSS we'd like to create a scheduled task as a file based configuration (so we can use an automation tool to deploy the severs). Is it possible?

When I create a DSS scheduled task manually, I don't see any new file created.

Indeed there's a registry resource created:

- /_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.tasks/definitions/-1234/DATA_SERVICE_TASK/api_agenda

-

```
<taskInfo>
    <locationResolverClass>org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.RoundRobinTaskLocationResolver</locationResolverClass>
    <locationResolverProperties/>
    <name>api_agenda</name>
    <properties>
        <entry>
            <key>DATA_SERVICE_TASK_NAME</key>
            <value>api_agenda</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>DATA_TASK_CLASS_NAME</key>
            <value>com.company.AgendaApiSynchronize</value>
        </entry>
    </properties>
    <taskClass>org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.task.DSTaskExt</taskClass>
    <triggerInfo>
        <disallowConcurrentExecution>true</disallowConcurrentExecution>
        <intervalMillis>14400000</intervalMillis>
        <misfirePolicy>DEFAULT</misfirePolicy>
        <repeatCount>-1</repeatCount>
    </triggerInfo>
</taskInfo>
```

When I create the registry resource and restart the server, the task is scheduled. But - is there a file-based configuration variant?

Thank you for any hint